# Listening and recording FM radio of phone on laptop

Tags: windows-7, android

I have android(Gingerbread) phone that I connect to laptop running Windows 7 Professional.

If I start FM radio on the phone can I

1. Listen to the songs through laptop speakers?
2. Record the songs being played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure -- all you need is a connecting cord, most likely with stereo mini-phone connectors at each end; this should cost no more than $2 if you need to buy it. You need to set up your laptop to "monitor", or play the audio (mic) input through the speakers. See http://blogs.creighton.edu/bluecast/tips-and-tricks/set-the-default-microphone-and-adjust-the-input-volume-in-windows-7/, for example.

There are a number of free applications that will record the audio, such as VLC, http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html, and Audacity (my favorite for audio), http://audacity.sourceforge.net/. Here's how to monitor recording in Audacity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB4MT9H8SjE

Comment: Thanx, I will have to check if the cable that has male pin on both the ends can do the trick because my phone FM radio will not start until I plug in the headphones.

Comment: with the android FM radios the headphones are the FM antenna, and that is (usually) the reason the headphones are required to be plugged in, vrses any "sencing" methods that observe resistance at the hedphone input. So as long as your other wire creates an antenna for the collection of RF is it likely to work. (use similar 1meter kind of wiring, vrses a short adapter)

Comment: @Psycogeek, nice info

Comment: An example of a cable you might use: http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/cb-424/1-ft.-3.5mm-m/m-audio-cable/1.html or http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/cb-461/24-dual-shielded-cable-w/3.5mm-phone-plugs/1.html, US$1.20 or $2.00.